# yq for merge strings

Tags: yaml, yq

I have following `prod.yaml` file

```
configMap:
  data: 
    env:
      APP_1: "{{ .Data.data.app_1 }}"
      APP_2: "{{ .Data.data.app_2 }}"
      APP_3: "{{ .Data.data.app_3 }}"
      APP_4: "{{ .Data.data.app_4 }}"
```

and `updated.yaml` file:

```
APP_1:
APP_2:
APP_3:
APP_4:
APP_5:
LOG_DIR:
```

The expected result is:

```
configMap:
  data: 
    env:
      APP_1: "{{ .Data.data.app_1 }}"
      APP_2: "{{ .Data.data.app_2 }}"
      APP_3: "{{ .Data.data.app_3 }}"
      APP_4: "{{ .Data.data.app_4 }}"
      APP_5:
      LOG_DIR:
```

I am using awk to format the fields new data fields

```
cat .env | awk -F":" '{print $1": \"{{ .Data.data."tolower($1)" }}\""}' > updated.yaml
```

And awk to merge the new fields

```
yq '.env[] *=n [load("update.yaml")]' prod.yaml > a.yaml
```

But I cannot update the prod.yaml file...

I am reading this documentation [yq doc](https://mikefarah.gitbook.io/yq/operators/multiply-merge#merge-only-new-fields)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With [mikefarah/yq](https://github.com/mikefarah/yq) that you are using, its pretty close to what you have. Remember that `.env` is a `!!map` type and not a `!!seq`, so do the recursive merge as the map type, i.e.

```bash
yq '.configMap.data.env *=n load("update.yaml")' prod.yaml
```

The above does not modify the file in-place. If you are satisfied with the contents of stdout, you could use the `-i` flag to do in-place substitution of the file

Comment: if my configMap.data.env in the prod.yaml file has no data. Can I run append of my data from the update.yaml file?

Comment: I'v solved it ! thanks!!